# Mysql stored procedure fetch error

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures

What am I doing wrong?

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `getAllPoints`()
BEGIN
declare done1, done2, done3, done4, pointAlive BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
*lots of declaring*
...
*lots of declaring*


declare cur1 cursor for select id, Owner_idOwner, longitude, lat,x,y from Point;
declare continue handler for not found set done1= TRUE;

DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP;
CREATE temporary TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP (
*lots of stuff*

)ENGINE=MEMORY;
open cur1;

mainLoop: loop
fetch cur1 into pointid, ownerid, pointlong, pointlat, pointx,pointy;

if done1 then 
set done1 = FALSE;
close cur1;
leave mainLoop;
end if;
insert into TEMP (тут работает);

BLOCK2:BEGIN
** Black is working right with cursor #1***

END BLOCK2 ;
BLOCK3:BEGIN
** Black is working right with cursor #2***
END BLOCK3;
```

That's what's not working:

`pointid` declared `int` with value "18045" fetched  from  cur1 cursor

```
call isAlive(pointid,@Alive,@timeTill);
update TEMP set Open = @Alive, TimeTill= @timeTill where Point_id = pointid;

end loop mainLoop;
select * from TEMP;
```

After calling `isAlive` loop seems to be interrupted and select query returns only 1 row with correct value in Open and TimeTill column instead of ~1200rows with correct values when isAlive is not called

END

This is the `isAlive` stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `isAlive`(IN iPoint_id int, INOUT Alive int, INOUT timeTill time)
BEGIN
declare pointAlive int;
select count(id) into pointAlive from Schedule where 
day = dayofweek(curdate())-1 
and Point_id = iPoint_id 
and Start < curtime() 
and Stop > curtime();

if poinTalive then
select pointAlive,timediff(Stop,curtime()) INTO Alive, timeTill
from Points.Schedule 
where day = dayofweek(curdate()) -1 
and Point_id = iPoint_id;
else
select pointAlive,timediff(str_to_date(concat(curdate(),' ',@starttime), "%Y-%m-%d %T"),now()) INTO Alive, timeTill
from Points.Schedule 
where day = dayofweek(curdate()) -1
and Point_id = iPoint_id;
end if;

END
```

Can you tell me what am I doing wrong? How can I call `isAlive` for every `pointid` ? Thank you

Comment: I recommend you use common_schema's rdebug tool to debug your stored procedure: https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/rdebug.html

Comment: Solved by adding one more block.... Thank you @Ike Walker